# How to make query to 'group by' using time range in sql?

Tags: sql

I have a problem to solve, in which get `detection class`counts like a car, motorcycle, bus, etc. From `stat` table I need to find the how many detection class detected in fix range of time on hourly, daily ect basis.
`stat` table data like this

[image]

From this table, I need to count detection_classes from `start_time` to `end_time` by group `track_id`, `detection_class` and `time_value`. I write query like:

```
SELECT detection_class, count(*) 
FROM (
      SELECT detection_class 
      FROM stats 
      where  source_id = "6d10586f61f64d71b1467a79093974ff" 
             AND detection_time <=end_time 
             AND detection_time >= start_time 
       group by track_id) as count 
 group by detection_class
```

Its result like below:

[image]

Now, I need to write query by which it gives me results hourly or daily, weekly, etc time period from `start_time` to `end_time`.

Comment: Generate "calendar table" - i.e. divide `(start_time, end_time)` range to according amount of needed ranges and use this table as one more data source in your query.

Comment: If a simplified representation of your start/end range is `(06:37, 23:42)`, and you are looking for hourly counts, does the first hour of your range begin at `06:37` or at `06:00`?

Comment: @pilcrow, this depends on start_timestemp, eg. start_timestamp = 1655144100 = 2022-6-14 date then I get data from start_timestamp to start_timestamp+3600, start_timestamp+3600 to start_timestamp+7200 like this

Comment: @Akina can you please, give any example for this. I didn't get exactly what you say.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=generate%20calendar%20table%20%5bmysql%5d

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.